# How do I execute this javascript on one div by ID?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have attempted to add `document.getElementByID("#divname")` but it hasn't work yet. I am learning on the fly and appreciate help that stack overflow users.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

promise = $.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    dataType:"text",
    url:"sgi.csv",
    cache:false
});

promise.done(function(data){

    var dataArr = data.split("\n");

    $.each(dataArr,function(){
        if (this != "") {

            var row = new String("");
            valArr = this.split(",");
                row += "<tr>"

            $.each(valArr, function(){
                row += "<td>" + this +"</td>"
            });     

                row += "</tr>"

             $('tbody').append(row);

        }

    });

});

// Run script if request fails
promise.fail(function() {
   console.log('A failure ocurred');
});

});
```

Comment: Are you trying to load rows in a div?

Comment: If you are using document.getElementByID you don't use the #, so document.getElementByID("divname")

Comment: Thanks Barry, where would I put this in my code?

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById('divName').append(var)`